# Update child records with parent records mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables one called `profile` and the other `pictures`. In the picture table there is a field that is supposed to have the parent_id inserted in the field. I used the below script in `MSSQL SERVER` and it worked but it fails to work on mysql

```
update pictures 
  set up_user_id = (
               select profile.profile_id 
                 from profile 
                where profile.email = pictures.email
              )
```

when i execute i get 0 rows affected.

Comment: Are you sure that there _should_ be any row affected?  Did you check your data?

Comment: is this for mysql or for sql-server ?

Comment: This query must be work,check both table properly and also make sure if you are making condition for specific row then use where clause in update statement

Comment: @GuidoG, it worked on mssql server but i'm now using it on mysql and it doesn't work

Comment: did you try running the sub query independently to see if there are rows?